# Issue while passing pointer to constant as an argument

Tags: c++, c, cppcheck

In this eg,using call by address concept in order to retrieve all the data changes which is happening in the function call...

In `main()`,

i)passing two arguments
         i)int pointer
         ii)pointer to constant -> which cannot change the value it is holding...

ii)Changing the values of int * and assigning some values to const void * in the function calls.

*Finally i'm trying to print the values in `main()`

*getting the int pointer values properly(no issues)

*getting the void pointer value as NULL..

Requirement:

Need to get the output in `main()` like this

main::ajskdffllagkdjdjdhdjhd(i mean to say that i need to print the void * values like this)

But i'm getting the value as main:: NULL

What shall i need to do inorder to get the expected output?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(int *len,const void *pBuf);
void func2(int **len,const void **pBuf);
void func3(int ***len,const void ***pBuf);
int main()
{
        int len = 0;
        const void *pBuf;
        printf("len b4 ::%d\n",len);
        printf("%p\n",&pBuf);
        func(&len,&pBuf);
        printf("len after::%d\n",len);
        printf("%p\n",&pBuf);
        printf("main::%s\n",(const char *)pBuf);
        return 0;
}

void func(int *len,const void *pBuf)
{
        *len = 20;
        printf("func1 :: %p\n",&pBuf);
        func2(&len,&pBuf);
}

void func2(int **len,const void **pBuf)
{
        printf("func2::%p\n",&pBuf);
        **len = 30;
        func3(&len,&pBuf);
}

void func3(int ***len,const void ***pBuf)
{
        const void *pMy = "ajskdffllagkdjdjdhdjhd";
        **pBuf = pMy;
        printf("func3::%p\n",&pBuf);
        printf("func3::%s\n",(const char *)**pBuf);
        ***len = 40;
}

Output:

len b4::0
0x7fffa9c51468
func1 :: 0x7fffa9c51440
func2::0x7fffa9c51420
func3::0x7fffa9c513f0
func3::ajskdffllagkdjdjdhdjhd
len after::40
0x7fffa9c51468
main::(null)
```

Comment: Are you preparing for the International Obfuscated C Code Contest?

Comment: Change your code to use properly typed pointers (`char*` instead of `void*`), eliminate the type casts to `const char*` and the compiler will tell you where you got it wrong.

Comment: This is known as three star programming. Clearly, the solution to all problems is to add more levels of indirection. Try adding a 4th star and see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are right with the string literal. Sorry.

However, you need to change the address where pBuf points to:

```
void func(int *len,const void **pBuf)
{
    *len = 20;
    printf("func1 :: %p\n",pBuf);
    func2(&len,&pBuf);
}

void func2(int **len,const void ***pBuf)
{
    printf("func2::%p\n",pBuf);
    **len = 30;
    func3(&len,&pBuf);
}

void func3(int ***len,const void ****pBuf)
{
    const void *pMy = "ajskdffllagkdjdjdhdjhd";
    ***pBuf = pMy;
    printf("func3::%p\n",&pBuf);
    printf("func3::%s\n",(const char *)***pBuf);
    ***len = 40;
}
```

`len` is an `int`. In order to change it, you need to call `func()` with the address of that `int` value.
`pBuf` is a pointer. To change the address where it points to, you need to call `func()` with the address of that pointer.

Comment: `"ajskdffllagkdjdjdhdjhd"` is a string literal, so it has static storage duration and a lifetime spanning the lifetime of the program. It continues to exist after the function returns.

Comment: I don't think so.It will available after function returns.

Comment: Tried declaring the const void * globally(same issue occuring)...Can u please explain how to put the string on the heap?

Comment: @Jayesh :: me too felt the same but i'm not getting the output like that....included the output along with the code..

Comment: @MichaelBurr : i expected the  same but its not happening...what shall i need to do inorder to make it happen

Comment: @Manidhan: change `**pBuf = pMy;` to `*(const void **)(**pBuf) = pMy;` or to `***(const void ****)pBuf = pMy;`.  Why those work is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You are catching address of `int` with single pointer and catching the address of `pointer` also with single pointer.. This is problem. In functions, change `*pBuf` as `**pBuf` and `**pBuf` as `***pBuf` and so on..